# Percentage calculation in view

Tags: 2013

I want to create a calculation that appears in my view... So far I have it looking like this. I want a % time usage calculation which takes total days used (numbers comes from a count field (odometer in) divided by days in the month  [image][image]t

Picture above is what I am trying to replicate

Answer (score 0):

A calculated column formatted as a number should work here. Once you've created that, you can use the same basic formula in the formula field to get the desired result with the appropriate list column names.

By choosing the number format for the calculated column, you can also check the box below the formula field to show it as a percentage and choose the number of decimal places.

Comment: but what calculation would I do to achieve that result?

Comment: I would think something along these lines:

Comment: which context were you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, previous comment got cut off... here's what I was thinking for the proposed formula: =SUM((Created-DateTime/In)/(Date/TimeIn-Date/TimeOut)). The first part for total time, then the second for the time used.

Comment: I got a syntax error when doing this code =SUM((Created-Date/Time In)/(Date/Time In-Date/Time Out))

Comment: Looking at it again, try removing the "SUM" after the =. So now it would read: =(Created-Date/Time In)/(Date/Time In-Date/Time Out)

Comment: =Created-[Date/Time In]/[Date/Time In]/[Date/Time Out] that worked but not sure if the parenthesis is in the right place... also what is the calculation doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
=MONTH(Created)
```

Gets you the Month number

```
=CHOOSE( MONTH(Created) , 31 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 )
```

Gets you the number of days in the month (take care of february yourself..)

The rest is clear I presume

HTH

Danny

Comment: I got those columns now.. my calculation should be "days used/daysInMonth" how would I determine the days used for that month....  what days used would be off of a dropdown vehical number... so for each vehical number has different records depending on how many days someone is taking it out... so for vehical 1 each time they take it out and bring it back in it would be one record... so now what calculation would I do to it checks the dropdown box to see which car it is and how many times it was used = days used....

Comment: Sound like you want *Relational Data*, but SharePoint is not a Relational Database. You need CSR (Client Side Rendering) script to process all items, then display the information, but CSR is only available since 2013. For 2010 you can to the same with some custom Javascript code.

Comment: how would I code it? through web part?

Comment: [CSR](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)